# Get particular value from array from LOOP

Tags: php, php-7

I am working on an appointment booking module with time slots.
I have a `foreach`-loop, which print out small boxes containing dates of next 7 days.

```php
foreach($week as $keys => $key){
?>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light modal-trigger" href="#moda1">
       <div class="date_cont" data-day="<?php echo $full_date[$keys]; ?>">
         <div class="c_month"><?php echo $key; ?></div>
         <div class="c_date"><?php echo $days[$keys]; ?></div>
       </div>
    </a>
<?php
}
```

There is a popup modal after loop showing available time slots which appears after clicking on any box. 
To show available time slots of that clicked box date, a query is run to fetch data of dates and check then disable the options from -> select option box.

Ex. user click on box containing valus= 28/aug/2019, then a popup appear and query run to check weather we have booking of 9am of 28/aug, if yes then disable the 9am select option by `jquery`.

All is going right but, problem is how can I get that clicked box date so I can run query and check available time slots? Is there any method to do this in a better way?

Comment: i'm assuming when the user clicks the modal you want the page to stay as it is and do some background process (database queries behind it and whatnot), you'd prolly need to make an xmlhttprequest

Comment: i don't ever use xml, can you suggest code just to get a date value in popup.

Comment: Trying to achieve this [https://preview.codecanyon.net/item/bookmyslot-appointment-booking-php-software/full_screen_preview/21908010?_ga=2.10839092.1886550055.1566831495-1435580110.1561272199]

Comment: okay il use another term, use AJAX

Answer (score 0):

use this format,

```php
<?php foreach($week as $keys => $key): ?>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light modal-trigger" href="#moda1">
       <div class="date_cont" data-day="<?php echo $full_date[$keys]; ?>">
         <div class="c_month"><?=$key?></div>
         <div class="c_date"><?=$days[$keys]?></div>
       </div>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```